# Cannot launch PhpStorm on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I've just installed PhpStorm on Ubuntu following step by step http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_running_PHPStorm_on_Ubuntu official tutorial.

When I try to launch /home/user/PhpStorm/phpstorm.sh I get this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main
```

So, com.intellij.idea.Main cannot be find or loaded. Can anybody help me? I have no idea how I should fix this.

Comment: Try to reinstall using gnu tar to unpack.

Comment: Hey!! why "off topic"? are you sure? it's a question about ubuntu and phpstorm, right? I had a problem how should I ask this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem was because of Archive Manager. The checkbox "Re-create folders" was unchecked that causes the broken folder structure. After reinstalling with the checked "Re-create folders", PhpStorm launched well!

Just in case, [here](http://starikovs.com/2013/03/02/install-phpstorm-on-ubuntu/) some info about this error.

Comment: So, the problem solved!